# Equivalence Relation Proof Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Determine if the following relation on $\mathbb R$ is an equivalence relation: **$a\sim{b}$ iff $|a-b|≤ 1$**

> Proof:
>
> **Reflexive:**
>   Suppose $a\in\mathbb R$. Then $|a-a| = 0$ which is real and less than or equal to $1$.
>   Thus $a\sim{a}$.
>
> **Symmetric:**
>   Suppose $a,b \in\mathbb R$ and $a\sim{b}$. Then $|a-b|$ is real.
>   Since $|b-a| = |a-b|$. Then $b-a$ is also real.
>   Thus $b\sim{a}$.
>
> **Transitive:**
>   Suppose $a,b,c \in\mathbb R$. Then $a\sim{b}$ and $b\sim{c}$.
>   So $|a-b|$ and $|b-c|$ are real.

I was double checking to see if my symmetric proof is correct. I know that the transitive part of the proof fails, but I am confused on how it fails.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to show that $|a-b|$ is real etc., unless your teacher insists.

Comment: And you need to show $|*-*|<1$

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry is easy: if $a\sim b$, then $|a-b| \leq 1$, by definition of $\sim$. But we know $|a-b| = |b-a|$, so $|b-a| \leq 1$, so $b \sim a$.

Hint on transitivity: draw a number line. If $a=2$ and $b=2.5$, then $a\sim b$. If $c=3.4$, then $b\sim c$ because $|3.4-2.5| = 0.9$. But $|a-c| = 1.4$, so $a \not\sim c$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $a ∼ b$ iff $|a-b| \le 1$, so whenever you want to prove the former, you must prove the latter. Usually it's unnecessary to state 'realness' if you use operations that the reals are closed under, but it is necessary to arrive at the latter condition.

For transitivity I believe you didn't get what it means:

∼ is transitive over $\mathbb{R}$ iff:

For any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$,

If $a∼b$ and $b∼c$,

$a∼c$

So to prove it you must arrive at exactly the same structure:

For any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$,

If $a∼b$ and $b∼c$,

$|a-b| \le 1$ and $|b-c| \le 1$

...  [insert attempt here]

$\color{#f00}{|a-c| \le 1}$  [it will be impossible to derive this]